# Intensity map based on a value of the each record

Tags: carto, heat-map

If I have geolocalized records with a simple true/false value for a field with title *"Do you like flowers?"*

How can I draw a map that shows me in which areas people like flowers more than in which areas like flowers less.

If I need to after-cook the data it is not a problem but I don't see how can I draw a kind of a "intensity/heat" map with the areas where people like flowers more. Remember that counting "yes" it not enough, has to be the difference between "yes"es and "no"es for each area.

The table would look like this:

```
Lat, Long, like flowers
1,   1,    y
3,   2,    n
4,   2,    n
4,   1,    y
```

And I would like to generate something like this:

[image]

Comment: To get a more helpful answer, I would suggest editing the question and/or the tags to the question to note what GIS software and what version of that software, you are using/have access to.  Without knowing the tools at your disposal, we can't help you use them.  Also, do you have regions (polygons) such as community zones, block groups, etc... you are trying to aggregate this by specifically (you don't have to, but it would likely change how you'd approach a solution).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @John I just added more explanations

Comment: just use CartoDB that provides that visualization with one click :)

Comment: @javisantana not really, I'm trying with #cartodb and it deals very good with density of population but not with density based on a weight calculation of one of their fields. The visualization wizard "Choropleth" is the most close to my needs but it colorizes every dot individually without aggregate dots in the proximity to generate an "area dot".

Comment: I understand. In that case you would need to do the aggregation using SQL. Not that simple but possible with this helper function: https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb-postgresql/blob/master/scripts-available/CDB_Hexagon.sql the query we use is this https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/blob/master/lib/assets/javascripts/cartodb/models/carto.js#L513 you would need to change the aggregation method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up in with (in CartoDB) was a combination of a [shapefile](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/import_shapefile_in_cartodb.html) with all the provinces in the area of my population, and [custom sql that updates a column into the shapefile table](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/counting_points.html) with the aggregated calculations of the records in each province. Then, everything rendered using the wizard "Choropleth".

If I manage to generate a shapefile with the hexagons of my example I could reproduce it exactly.

Check [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/134018/46297).

Check also this [@javisantana comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133849/intensity-map-based-on-a-value-of-the-each-record?noredirect=1#comment192858_133849).

Answer (score 1):

Here's [a tutorial on 'hex binning' using free and open source tools](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/binning-alternative-point-maps/), and [another](http://geospatial.commons.gc.cuny.edu/2013/11/25/hexbinning/). A couple of years old, but may still be applicable. Once you have the hexagons, it should be easy to import and style by intensity in cartodb.

Basic steps

1. Install [QGIS](http://www2.qgis.org/en/site/)
2. Install the [MMQGIS plugin](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/)
3. Use the [MMQGIS "Create Grid Layer" tool](http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/) to create hexagonal grid at your desired resolution.
4. Import your "yes" and "no" data as `csv`. In QGIS 2+, Click on `Layers` ‣ `Add Delimited Text Layer`.
5. Use the [QGIS "Point in Polygon" tool](http://maps.cga.harvard.edu/qgis/wkshop/pt_in_pgn.php) to sum **both** "yes" and "no" counts within each hexagon. Sum each field ("yes" and "no") to its own column for use the next step. If you have a lot of points, this step [might be more efficient in PostGIS](http://geospatial.commons.gc.cuny.edu/2013/11/25/hexbinning/).
6. If as you say, the important thing is the difference between total "yes" and "no" in each hexagon, then add a new field, and use the [QGIS Field Calculator](http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html) to calculate the difference between the "yes" and "no" fields created in the last step.
7. Assuming this ultimately goes to cartodb, import the hexagon shapefile to cartodb and [symbolize by intensity](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/conditional_styling.html).