# Colorise China Provinces using CartoDB?

Tags: carto, china

I have a table with the China provinces and a numeric value associate to each one, how I can colorise the China provinces based on these values?, like a "intensity" scale.

I'm using CartoDB.

An example of the table can be:

```
Province,     Value
Tibet,        100
Sichuan,      90
Yunnan,       10
Guizhou,      45
Anhui,        50 
Heilongjiang, 120
Gansu,        98
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the shapefile map with the China provinces, one source can be: http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-1-states-provinces/
2. Upload it to your CartoDB account as it is explained here: http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/import_shapefile_in_cartodb.html
3. Add a new field to the new table in the CartoDB interface, let's call it *"shape_value"*
4. Update *"shape_value"* with your values
5. Use the wizard "Choropleth" to colorise provinces based on the column *"shape_value"*